# R dplyr resolve variable in conditional filter

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, standard-evaluation

I am trying to filter based on a variable value, and have tried multiple combinations of filter_, dots and quotes to no avail.

As an example, I have a

```
runlist = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

and a dataframe boo

```
run <- rep(seq(5), 3)
edge1 <- sample(20, 15)
edge2 <- sample(20, 15)
weights <- sample(50, 15)
boo <- as.data.frame(cbind(run, edge1, edge2, weights))
```

and I want to filter a dataframe named boo which may look something like
iteratively as

```
for (i in runlist) {
    bop <- boo %>% filter( run == i )
    str(boo)
}
```

I suspect I'll be hearing about not using for loops and R, rather use `group_by(run)`, but I'm sending this data to `igraph` and need to further subset the dataset to just edges and weights, thus losing the grouping variable, as in

```
bop <- boo %>% filter( run == i ) %>% select( edge1, edge2, weights )
```

I will create a network graph and find density and centrality values for each run.

```
bing <- graph.data.frame(bop)
```

How do I get the `i` in the conditional filter to resolve as the correct index?

Comment: use `for (i in unique(boo$run))` instead

Comment: @Nate Day Wow, yes, that works. Could you explain to me why your suggestion works while `runlist = unique(boo$run)` and indexing on `runlist` does not? And how do I correctly @ your handle which has a space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is not about "resolving a variable in a conditional filter", but there's a much easier way to do what you want to do.

The big idea is to split the data frame based on the variable `run`, and map a function onto each of those pieces. This function takes a piece of the data frame and spits out an igraph.

The following code accomplishes the above, storing a list of graphs in the column `graph`. (It's a list-column, see more at the [R for data science book](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html))

```
boo %>%
  group_by(run) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(graph = map(data, function(x) graph.data.frame(x %>% select(edge1, edge2, weights)))) %>%
  mutate(density = map(graph, function(x) graph.density(x))
```

Comment: intruiguing . . . I'll try it out and see if I can get the centrality and density stats I want. I like the was you inserted the selection into the graph call.

Comment: So I've got the list-column of graphs, but I haven't been successful in using the graphs individually to obtain densities and centralities stats. I've even mirrored your suggestion and tried `PDensities <- PGraphs %>% mutate(PDensity = map(data, function(x) graph.density(x)))` but recieve Not a graph object error messages. Thanks also for sending the docs link, very interesting, bu it recommends broom which doesn't appear to tidy network graphs. How would I obtain, for example, graph.density for each of the graphs? I'd love to use this method.

Comment: Each graph is stored as a cell in the data frame. You could extract the graph iin say, the 2nd row and 3rd column with `my_dataframe[2, 3]` just like as usual. There's probably a more efficient mapping operation, which maps an extract function to each cell of the list column. But the fundamental idea is that you can extract things from the list column just as any column.

Comment: I added an operation to the pipeline that takes in the graphs and spits out the density.

Comment: That works, and is fast. Thanks so much, I'm using this.